# Django form. Why is my queryset showing undefined even though my model is linked in the meta?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm attempting to change the way the many to many selections on my Django form is displayed. I attempted to follow this guide. https://medium.com/swlh/django-forms-for-many-to-many-fields-d977dec4b024. The code I am attempting to recreate is below.

```
class CreateMealForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Meal
        fields = [‘name’, ‘date’, ‘members’]
    name = forms.CharField()
    date = forms.DateInput()
    members = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Member.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
    )
```

However when I recreate this I get the error that "users" is not defined. The code I am using is below.

```
from dataclasses import fields
from django import forms
from boat.models import Mission
from .models import Sortie
class FinalSortie(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Sortie
        fields = ['start_date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'notable_events', 'server_name', 'server_pass', 'mission',
                  'Sortie_name', 'users']
    user = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=users.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

I have attempted to Google, YouTube, and Stack overflow search but I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any guidance or help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: attaching error, and model

```
class Sortie(models.Model):
    Sortie_name = models.CharField(default="NoName", max_length=50)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
    notable_events = models.TextField(null=True)
    server_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    server_pass = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    mission = models.ForeignKey(Mission, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(DiscordUser)
```

`NameError: name 'users' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

When creating your queryset, you use:

```
queryset=users.objects.all(),
```

However, looking at your field, users is a fieldname, not a model.

```
users = models.ManyToManyField(DiscordUser)
```

So your queryset should be referring to the model name, eg

```
queryset=DiscordUser.objects.all(),
```